# Compiling a program using exec()

Tags: c, unix, compilation, exec, system-calls

I have a process P1. I want this process to produce the executable of <progname.c> by running the command:

```
gcc -Wall <progname>.c -o <progname>
```

I am not allowed to use system(). I want this to be done with exec() but don't know how.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you read [the manual page for exec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)? Which part didn't you understand?

Comment: I'm not sure after reading the manual whether exec compiles with flag -Wall or not. Also I'm not sure if I should use execl or execv. To be honest I didn't understand very well the difference between them.

Comment: Re -Wall: try it and see. Re execl vs. execv: the difference is just how you pass the command-line parameters to them. They work exactly the same other than that.

Comment: `execl` takes a list of distinct arguments, so you can simply do `execl("/usr/bin/gcc", "/usr/bin/gcc", "-Wall", "foo.c", "-o", "foo", NULL);`  With execv, you need to create an array.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @WilliamPursell Is it correct instead of "foo.c" to do:  char*str = "foo"      and then:         execl("/usr/bin/gcc", "/usr/bin/gcc", "-Wall", str.c, "-o", str, NULL);                                          Is it possible to give me an example how the same command would be with execv?    Thank you in advance

Comment: You would need 2 different strings.  Something like `const char *base = "foo";  char name[32]; sprintf(name, "%s.c", base); const char *gcc = "/usr/bin/gcc"; execl(gcc, gcc, "-Wall", name, "-o", base);`